# Queue click() events with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to somehow attach a click event handler to an element, which will be called after all others?

I have an another click event handler registered with `.click()` and I'd like to attach another function call, which will be executed after the previous one, without using `setTimeout()`.

Cheers,
Till

Comment: When you attach multiple events, the callbacks will automatically be called after one another when the event occurs. There is no problem. Am I missinterpreting your question?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I can't influence the order. Is it possible to somehow register a callback in a different way, so it's called later?

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers are called in the order they're registered.  If you register this one last, it'll get called last.

Comment: but you are not guaranteed that the last handler starts after the first one finished.

Comment: @Christoph AFAIK, you are, if the individual handlers only perform synchronous operations.

Comment: true,though the `setTimeout()` led me to the conclusion it's not only synchronous, but that's up to the OP to clarify I guess.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I can't influence the order. Is it possible to somehow register a callback in a different way, so it's called later?

Comment: why can't you influence the order?  Please show some code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Because it's a plugin, my code is executed before the core code and I can't hook in after it.